# Simple generic cartesian product in C++

Tags: c++, combinatorics, generics

The idea is to take a sequence of sequences (of the same type) and use tuples of `[iterator, current index, sequence size]` to keep track of the current state, such that the `cartesian_product` object can return one sequence at a time.

General questions:

- bugs? (would hope not!)
- code quality ok? anything i've missed?
- is there a simpler way to keep track of the object state (iterators, counts, etc)
- would it make sense to make this into an iterator (it could probably be bidirectional?)

Improvement ideas:

- when the number of sequences is known at compile time, maybe it would be better for `next()` to return a tuple/static array instead of a `std::vector<T>`?
- use a simple aggregate type instead of a tuple to avoid all the `std::get` ugliness?

Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class cartesian_product {
public:
    template <typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > 1)>::type>
    cartesian_product(Args&&... args)
        : count(1)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor 1\n";
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "T must be an arithmetic type.");
        append(args...);
    }

    cartesian_product(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& sequences) 
        : count(1)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor 2\n";
        tuples.reserve(sequences.size());
        for(auto&& s : sequences) {
            tuples.emplace_back(s.cbegin(), 0ul, s.size());
            count *= s.size();
        }
    }

    cartesian_product(std::vector<std::vector<T>>&& sequences)
        : cartesian_product(sequences)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor 3\n";
    }


    bool has_next() { return count > 0; }

    // next combination
    std::vector<T> next()
    {
        std::vector<T> res(tuples.size());
        auto s = res.rbegin();

        for (auto p = tuples.rbegin(); p < tuples.rend(); ++p, ++s) {
            *s = *std::get<0>(*p);

            if (p > tuples.rbegin()) {
                auto q = p - 1;
                if (std::get<1>(*q) == std::get<2>(*q)) {
                    std::get<0>(*q) -= std::get<2>(*q);
                    std::get<1>(*q) = 0;

                    ++std::get<0>(*p);
                    ++std::get<1>(*p);
                }
            } else {
                ++std::get<0>(*p);
                ++std::get<1>(*p);
            }
        }

        --count;
        return res;
    }

private:
    using I = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    using E = std::tuple<I, std::size_t, std::size_t>;
    std::vector<E> tuples;
    int count;

    template <typename... Args>
    void append(std::vector<T> const& vec, Args&&... args)
    {
        append(vec);
        append(args...);
    }

    void append(std::vector<T> const& vec)
    {
        count *= vec.size();
        tuples.emplace_back(std::cbegin(vec), 0ul, vec.size());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> a { 1, 2 };
    std::vector<int> b { 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> c { 5, 6 };
    std::vector<int> d { 7, 8, 9 };

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> s{ a, b, c, d };

    cartesian_product<int> p(a, b, c);
    cartesian_product<int> q(s);
    cartesian_product<int> r(std::vector<std::vector<int>>{ a, b, c, d });

    auto print = [](auto&& vec) { for (auto v : vec) std::cout << v << " "; std::cout << "\n"; };

    while (p.has_next())
        print(p.next());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247972/cartesian-product-of-two-vector-spaces The answer ends being a generalization for the cartesian product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't limit Cartesian products to arithmetic types

You shouldn't limit your class to only allow products of vectors of a type that satisfies `std::is_arithmetic`. Why shouldn't I be able to do a Cartesian product of a `std::string` and a `std::chrono::time_point` for example? There is no actual multiplication involved in a Cartesian product after all.

## Your class will likely force copies of vectors to be made

In this constructor:

```
cartesian_product(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& sequences) {...}
```

The parameter `sequences` is a reference, so you might think that this doesn't cause any copies to be made. However, that is only true if the caller already has a vector of vectors lying around. In your own example usage in `main()`, you have four vectors `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, but then you create the vector of vectors `s` which causes a copy to be made of the four original vectors. And the following line constructs a temporary that also makes copies:

```
cartesian_product<int> r(std::vector<std::vector<int>>{ a, b, c, d });
```

## Support more containers besides `std::vector`

You only support products of `std::vector<T>`, but what if I have my data in a regular array, a `std::array`, a `std::list` or any other container? Again, it is an unnecessary restriction. Try to rewrite it so any type of container works. Either have it accept a reference to a container object directly, or have it accept iterators like the STL algorithms do.

## Return a tuple instead of a vector

A `std::vector` will allocate memory on the heap, which will impact performance. And since you know the size of the result, you can return a `std::tuple` instead, which has the advantage that it can be unpacked using C++17's [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). Apart from that, with a `std::tuple` the value types of each input vector/array/etc can be different, whereas your solution requires all of them to be the same,

## Add iterators to your class

Indeed, it makes sense to add iterators to your class. In fact, it already basically keeps track of everything that an iterator would do, and `next()` is the equivalent of an iterator's `operator++()`. Ideally, you want to be able to write something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> a_vector{"foo", "bar", "baz"};
std::list<int> b_vector{4, 5, 6, 7};

for (auto [a_element, b_element]: cartesian_product(a_vector, b_vector))
    std::cout << a_element << ", " << b_element << "\n";
```

And then expect the following result:

```
foo, 4
foo, 5
foo, 6
foo, 7
bar, 4
bar, 5
...
```

This also avoids the need for a `has_next()` function.

Comment: thanks! will edit the post with the updated implementation when it's done.

Comment: @BogdanB You shouldn't update this post, instead create a new post with your updated code.

Comment: thanks for the comment. yeah, I guess it's better practice to make a new post and link to this one for context.